# Are react's lifecycle method autobound? If not should we be binding them with .bind(this)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I think the title is pretty self-descriptive.

I've building react components using the class notation, and I noticed that while `handleSomething` has to be manually bound to `this`, `render` and `componentWillMount` do not. Are method bound to `this` already? Is it ok to bind manually for notationally consistency's sake?

Comment: No, they're not bound, they just get called as methods?

Comment: How do they have access to `this.props` and `this.state`, then? And do they not have access to that a bound method would have access to?

Comment: I don't understand. When you call `component.render()` (which React does), then `this` inside `render` will refer to the `component` and have access to its `.state` and `.props` properties. When you call `component.render.call(null)`, then it won't work.

Comment: All methods in a component are exactly the same, the difference with `handlers` is that you pass them using the function reference. e.g. `onClick={this.handleClick}` and this is not bound to anything by default, that's why you need to bind it. If you were to call it like this `component.handleClick()` then you wouldn't need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Understanding of 'this' in JavaScript

The 'this' keyword in a function is determined by the executing scope of the function. For example, the `this` in `someFunction` when calling with `obj.someFunction()` will be `obj`.

A more concrete example:

```js
function handleClick() {
    console.log(this.state.value);
}

var state = { value: 1 }; // declare a var in window
console.log("handleClick()");
handleClick(); // Logged 1. The 'this' in the method will be window, because the method is called in window


var obj = {
  state: { value: 2 },
  handleClick: function() {
    console.log(this.state.value);
  },
};
console.log("obj.handleClick();");
obj.handleClick(); // Logged 2. The 'this' is referred to obj because the method is called in obj.

// let's reassign the function to a temp var in window
var temp = obj.handleClick;
console.log("temp()");
temp(); // Logged 1. The 'this' in the function is referred to window because the method is called in window.
console.log("window.temp()");
window.temp(); // this is equal to the one above.

console.log("temp.bind(obj)");
temp.bind(obj)(); // Logged 2. Bind the method and call the method, so the 'this' in the function is referred to obj.

console.log("temp.bind(this)");
temp.bind(this)(); // Logged 1. Since this in the executing scope is window. This effectively is the same calling in this.

console.log("temp.bind(window)");
temp.bind(window)(); // Logged 1. This is equal to the one above.
```

Try it here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvOpEa?editors=0012

A blog post about this: https://hackernoon.com/understanding-javascript-the-this-keyword-4de325d77f68

## Back to your question

If you look at `render`, `componentWillMount`, and `handleSomething` you defined in your class, it will become apparent why you need to bind your handler to `this`.

### render

```
// Rerender
ReactCurrentOwner.current = workInProgress;
var nextChildren = void 0;
{
  ReactDebugCurrentFiber.setCurrentPhase('render');
  nextChildren = instance.render();
  if (debugRenderPhaseSideEffects) {
    instance.render();
  }
  ReactDebugCurrentFiber.setCurrentPhase(null);
}
```

This is how react call `redner()`, where the instance is the object instance that has state, props, etc. You can try it very easily by putting a breakpoint in your render method and go back a call stack.

### handleSomething

For example, if you define your class like this, with `handleSomething` as the `onClick` callback method of the button.

```
class Button extends Component {
  handleSomething() {
    // 'this' will be undefined.
  }

  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.handleSomething}>Test</button>);
  }
}
```

If you click the button, this is how react calls the onClick handler method.

```
  function callCallback() {
    fakeNode.removeEventListener(evtType, callCallback, false);
    // This is where react calls your method.
    func.apply(context, funcArgs);
    didError = false;
  }
```

where `func` is `handleSomething`, and `context` is usually `undefined` in my debugging experience, and `funcArgs` is the arguments that being passed in the function.

`apply` is similar to `bind`. The first argument is used to specify the `this` of the function, and the second argument is an array of parameters to pass into the function.

See MDN for more information about `apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

In this case, the method `handleSomething` is being called with `undefined` as `this`; Therefore, if you didn't bind the method, your `this` will be `undefined`.

> I noticed that while handleSomething has to be manually bound to this,
>   render and componentWillMount do not. Are method bound to this
>   already?

They are called with the instance of your class, so they already have `this` as your instance without using `bind`. I guess you can kind of say it's already bound to `this`.

> Is it ok to bind manually for notationally consistency's sake?

You don't need to bind `this` with react's lifecycle methods. If you really want to, I guess you can bind those methods to `this` as well (there might be some side effects that I don't know, since I didn't really look that deeply into their source), but this is like doing `obj.handleClick.bind(obj)();` instead of `obj.handleClick();`. It is unnecessary and will spend some clock cycles doing something that's not needed.