# React: Component cannot recognize a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my App component I call **checkUserAuth()** method in order check if user is logged in or not and render different content according to this.  It works fine when I call it via componentDidMount() method however it doesn't work If I try to call it via another method:

```
TypeError: this.checkUserAuth is not a function
```

In my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

      this.state = {
      loggedIn: false
      };

      this.checkUserAuth = this.checkUserAuth.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.checkUserAuth(); // here this method can be called
  }

  checkUserAuth(){
    const loggedUser = AuthService.isAuthenticated();
    if(loggedUser){
    store.dispatch(actions.loginSuccess());
    this.setState({loggedIn: true});
    }
  }


  logoutUser(){
    store.dispatch(actions.logout());
    this.checkUserAuth(); // here it return errors
  }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: how you are calling the   logoutUser method.

Comment: Lifecycle methods are always called with the context of `this` being the class instance whereas your method is most likely called like `this.logoutUser()` meaning inside your function, `this` will refer to the function itself. That is why you have to bind your function but not `componentDidMount` in order for it to work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49504319/9381601) explains in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this in the constructor:

```
this.logoutUser = this.logoutUser.bind(this);
```

Also, consider using an auto-binding library if you find it tedious to always bind stuff. I use react-autobind